# No prefetched files with preload-webpack-plugin

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

I have a question related to prefetching and preloading.

1. I have vue app and after build I receive double loaded files in my dist/index.html. You can see it below.
2. Moreover the "scripts" are not preloaded/prefetched. I do not know why. I have a plugin installed.

   ```
   <head>
   <title></title>
   <link href=/app.128b43f14088f83cb6c0.js rel=preload as=script>
   <link href=/chunk-vendors.128b43f14088f83cb6c0.js rel=preload as=script>

   <div id=app></div>
   <script src=/chunk-vendors.128b43f14088f83cb6c0.js></script>
   <script src=/app.128b43f14088f83cb6c0.js></script>
   ```

vue.config.js

```
modules.export = {
    configureWebpack: () => {
        return {
            devtool: 'source-map',
            output: {
                filename: '[name].[hash].js',
                chunkFilename: '[name].[hash].js'
            },
            plugins: [
                new PreloadWebpackPlugin(),
                new CleanWebpackPlugin()
            ],
            resolve: {
                alias: {
                   styles: path.join(__dirname, 'src/assets')
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have vue app and after build I receive double loaded files in my dist/index.html.

Vue CLI already injects its own [preload plugin](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#preload), so your plugin is duplicating the preload/prefetch. Simply remove yours to resolve the duplication.

You should stick with the one already provided by Vue CLI, as it's modified to work with the Vue CLI toolchain. If you prefer to use your own for some reason, you could remove the built-in plugin with:

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.plugins.delete('preload')
    config.plugins.delete('prefetch')
  }
}
```

Comment: how to set specific file to be preloaded instead of prefetched? I have some chunk foo.ffgrg43423vf.css which is prefetched. I want to keep everything like it is instead of this one file which should be preloaded

Comment: @Sheppard26 I recommend asking that as a new question, so that someone familiar with the topic can provide an answer you might find helpful.